# How to show that the cuspidal cubic is not smooth using the formal smoothness criterion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X/k$ be the cuspidal cubic over an algebraically closed field? How do I show that this is not formally smooth?

The definition I am using for formally smooth is the one at the stacks project:

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GZ

What I really want to know is the following : a smooth morphism should roughly correspond to being a submersion, yes? If so, why is the cuspidal cubic not smooth? I guess we can be change to a scheme over which the map on tangents spaces is not smooth?

Comment: So first of all, in this case you should be considering the structure morphism $f:C \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$. One of the requirements of ordinary smoothness of a morphism is that it have regular geometric fibers, which $f$ obviously does not. So what you really need to show is that formal smoothness implies this obviously false geometric fact. Or you could (per Lemma 36.11.6) try mucking around with equations and show that the natural map $k \to H^0(C,\mathcal O_C)$ is not formally smooth in the algebraic sense.

Comment: What I was really hoping for was some nice choice of T and T' such that there was no lift possible (using notation from the stacks project link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can guess such a choice of $T$ and $T'$ from the "picture". Consider the cuspidal cubic $y^2=x^3$. The line $x=0$ intersects the cusp at order 2, but it appears to leave the curve afterwards.

In equations, consider the ring map $k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)\to k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ given by $x\to 0$ and $y\to \epsilon$. This is well-defined since $(0)^3-(\epsilon^2)=0$ if we are modding out by $\epsilon^2$.

Now, let's try to lift this map to $k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^3)$. Suppose we have a map $k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)\to k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^3)$, where $x$ maps to $a\epsilon^2$ and $y$ maps to $\epsilon+b\epsilon^2$. Then, substituting in the equation $x^3=y^2$, we get $0=(a\epsilon^2)^3=(\epsilon+b\epsilon^2)^2=\epsilon^2$, which is a contradiction.

The way I think about this is that the cuspidal curve is a 1-dimensional thing, but it's tangent space at the origin is 2-dimensional. Therefore, there are some "phantom directions" that are in the tangent space but can't be extended to actual "jets" along the curve.

Comment: Ah I see. What was throwing me off was the that the order of intersection is 2 so we should consider higher order infinitesimals. Thanks!